# Left Outer Join with Missing Records

Tags: mysql, left-join

I'm selecting data from several tables, but the main idea is that a product may or may not have a discount record associated with it, as either a percent off or dollar off amount. I'm using a left outer join (which may be incorrect) and am getting back the same values for dollar and percent values, regardless as to whether or not the records exist.

The query looks something like:

```
SELECT Items.ItemID, Items.name, Items.price, 
       ItemDiscounts.percentOff, ItemDiscounts.dollarOff, 
       ItemAttributes.ColorName, ItemStuff.StuffID
FROM Items, ItemAttributes, ItemStuff
LEFT OUTER JOIN ItemDiscounts
  ON ItemDiscounts.ItemID = ItemID
  AND (
    ItemDiscounts.percentOff > 0
    OR ItemDiscounts.dollarOff > 0
  )
WHERE Items.ItemID = ItemAttributes.ItemID
AND ItemStuff.ItemID = Items.ItemID
GROUP BY ItemStuff.StuffID
```

The weird part is that in all results, `percentOff` returns "1", and `dollarOff` returns "0", regardless if each item has it's own associated discount record. For spits, I changed `ItemDiscounts.percentOff > 0` to `ItemDiscounts.percentOff > 1`, then `dollarAmount` changed to all 2's and `percentOff` was all 0's.

I'm somewhat baffled on this, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is there a `GROUP BY` or any aggregate function (SUM,COUNT..) not shown here?

Comment: There is a GROUP BY, yes. I mocked the query to make it shorter and not expose actual table/column names, will edit to show the group

Comment: Try selecting GROUP_CONCAT(ItemDiscounts.dollarOff) instead of ItemDiscounts.dollarOff to see if GROUP BY is hiding any of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an unqualified reference to ItemID in your ON clause... not clear why that's not throwing an "ambiguous column" exception.  (Apparently, it's not ambiguous to MySQL, and MySQL is determining which ItemId is being referenced, the odds are good that its not the one you intended.

Also, your query includes references to the `ItemStuff` rowsource, but there is no such rowsource shown in your query.

I also suspect that the behavior of the `GROUP BY` that is giving you a result set that doesn't meet your expectation. (More than likely, right now, it's masking the real problem in your query, which could be a `CROSS JOIN` operation that you didn't intend.

I suggest you try your query without the `GROUP BY` clause, and confirm the resultset is what you would expect absent the GROUP BY clause.

NOTE: Most other relational database engines will throw an exception with a `GROUP BY` like you show in your query. They (basically) require that every non-aggregate in the SELECT list be included in the `GROUP BY`. You can get MySQL to behave the same way (with some particular settings of sql_mode.)  MySQL is more liberal, but the result set you get back may not conform to your expectation.

NOTE: I don't see how this query is passing a semantics check, and is returning any resultset at all, given the references to a non-existent `ItemStuff` rowsource.

---

For improved readability, I recommend that you not use the comma as the join operator, and that you instead use the JOIN keyword. I also recommend that you move the join predicates from the `WHERE` clause to an `ON` clause. I also prefer to give an alias to each rowsource, and use that alias to qualify the columns from it.

Given what you show in your query, I'd write (the parts I can make sense of) like this:

```
SELECT i.ItemID
     , i.name
     , i.price
     , d.percentOff
     , d.dollarOff
     , a.ColorName
  FROM Items i 
  JOIN ItemAttributes a
    ON a.ItemID = i.ItemID
  LEFT 
  JOIN ItemDiscounts d
    ON d.ItemID = i.ItemID
       AND ( d.percentOff > 0 OR d.dollarOff > 0 )
```

I've omitted `ItemStuff.StuffID` from the SELECT list, because I don't see any `ItemStuff` rowsource.

I also exclude the WHERE clause, because I don't see any `ItemStuff` rowsource in your query.

```
-- WHERE ItemStuff.ItemID = i.ItemID
```

I omit the GROUP BY because, again, I don't see any ItemStuff rowsource in your query, and because the behavior of the GROUP BY is likely not what I expect, but is rather masking a problem in my query.

```
-- GROUP BY ItemStuff.StuffID
```

---

**UPDATE:**

@Kyle, the fact your query "timed out" leads me to believe you are generating WAY MORE rows than you expect, like you have a Cartesian product (every row from a table is being "matched" to every row in some other table... 10,000 rows in one table, 10,000 rows in the other table, that will generate 100,000,000 rows.

I think the `GROUP BY` clause is masking the real problem.

I recommend that for development, you include the PRIMARY KEY of each table as the leading columns in your result set.  I would add some reasonable predicates to the driving table (e.g. `i.ItemID IN (2,3,5,7)` to limit the size of the result set, and ORDER BY the primary key... that should help you identify an unintended Cartesian product.

Comment: The lack of `ItemStuff` was a typing error. Simply removing the GROUP BY made my query time out. I'll look into moving the WHERE clauses into joins

Comment: @Kyle, the fact your query "timed out" leads me to believe you are generating WAY MORE rows than you expect, like you have a Cartesian product (every row from a table is being "matched" to every row in some other table... 10,000 rows in one table, 10,000 rows in the other table, that will generate 100,000,000 rows. The `GROUP BY` is masking your problem.

Comment: Yeah. I've looked into it more, and the GROUP BY was put there by another developer to mask the fact that a supposed "one to one" relationship is actually a "one to many". In reality, our 10 year old database is so far from normalized, that I'll probably have to take a different route. I'll accept your answer on the basis that it seems most helpful to someone with a similar issue. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get what you want when you remove these lines from your query?

AND (
    ItemDiscounts.percentOff > 0
    OR ItemDiscounts.dollarOff > 0
  )

Comment: Same results... 1 for `percentOff`, 0 for `dollarOff`

Answer (score 0):

Once you specify an absolute value for the possibly-null side of an outer join, your `WHERE` clause has to account for it.

Try it with the following clause:

```
AND (
ItemDiscounts.percentOff > 0
OR ItemDiscounts.percentOff is null
OR ItemDiscounts.dollarOff > 0
OR ItemDiscounts.dollarOff is null
)
```

Additionaly, you're specifying a `GROUP BY` without an aggregate.  This makes no sense in most cases.  You probably want `ORDER BY` to sort.